Put a formula once a cell is populated
I'm trying to write a VBA formula where if the cell after the last used row in column A is populated, then a formula will appear in column C in the newly populated row. My issue is that the code below will populate the code only after the new row in column A is populated, but then the value is deleted. I need column C to populate as column A is populated. Below is what I have so far.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    ' Define the range of rows to check
    lastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Turn off events to prevent infinite loop
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Check if any cell within the defined range has changed
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Row = lastRow + 1 Then
            Me.Cells(lastRow + 1, "C").formula = "=XLOOKUP($A" & lastRow + 1 & ",Inventario!$A:$A,Inventario!C:C)"
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Turn on events
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Thank you in advanced for all the help!

Also why check for last row? directly enter the formula in C if A is populated. Lesser code... If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then. Unless there is a header row or some other restriction which I am sure can be easily handled?

If you set up your data range as a table and all formulas in that column are the same (i.e., XLOOKUP()), then the formula will be inserted automatically when a new row is added. VBA wouldn't be necessary.

A Worksheet Change: VBA XLOOKUP
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim lcell As Range: Set lcell = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    
    If Intersect(lcell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        lcell.EntireRow.Columns("C").Formula = "=XLOOKUP(" _
            & lcell.Address(0) & ",Inventario!A:A,Inventario!C:C)"
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

